# PHP login and session get data from databse

Tags: php, session

This is my code in login. After login i want to userid as primary key to pass another page. i try many code but still not working. please help me

```
if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $password=md5($_POST['password']);
        $sql ="SELECT * FROM tbluser WHERE EmailAddress=:email and uPassword=:password";
        $query= $dbh -> prepare($sql);
        $query-> bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query-> bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query-> execute();
        $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        if($query->rowCount() > 0)
        {
            $_SESSION['login']=$_POST['email'];
            $_SESSION['fname']=$results->FullName;
            $_SESSION['uid']=$results['UserID'];
            $currentpage=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = '$currentpage'; </script>";
        } else{

            echo "<script>alert('Invalid Details');</script>";

        }

    }
```

And how to call the userid in another page.

Comment: `md5()`is obsolete for hashing passwords and should *not be used*. PHP provides [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), please use them. And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet). If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Don't use JavaScript or Meta Tags to redirect a web page. Use [`Location: header`](//stackoverflow.com/q/768431/) instead. Check [PHP the Right Way](//phptherightway.com/) for more up-to-date advice.

Comment: Are you sure `$currentpage` is set and has a correct value?

Comment: OK, Thank for recommendation .`$currentspage` for call current page viewwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need `session_start()`

```
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
            {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['login']=$_POST['email'];
                $_SESSION['fname']=$results->FullName;
                $_SESSION['uid']=$results['UserID'];
                $currentpage=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = '$currentpage'; </script>";
            }
```

and then you start the session with session_start() on the other page and it will work.

Comment: ALL page need a session_start() to use session

Comment: @MuhammadWazexr use session_start() on top of every page,that way $_SESSION variables will be stored

Comment: @Dice Ok sir. but this code correct? `$_SESSION['uid']=$results['UserID'];`

Comment: Yes. Take off the email, you can get it easily with a query once you have userID

Answer (score -1):

That's how you use a session, put it at beginning or every php file where you need it

```
 <?php

        session_start();

        include("./Models/db_connect.php");
        include('./Controllers/Functions/PHP/messages.php');
        include('./Models/actual_date.php');
        $actual_date = get_date($db);

        switch(isset($_POST['login'])):  
            case 'Register':
            $email = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['em']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
            $password = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['pw']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

            // check if the combination fname/lname/email is already used
            include('./Models/log_check.php');
            unset($_SESSION['ID'],$_SESSION['role']);
            $_SESSION['ID'] = $row['ID'];
            $_SESSION['role'] = $row['role'];

            if(intval($row['ID']) > 0){
                include('./Models/status_update.php');
                $successmsg = "Connexion réussie! Redirection en cours";
                header('refresh:5;url=./index.php?page=Lobby');
                if($_SESSION['role'] === 'vet') {
                    include './Views/html_top_vets.php'; 
                } else {
                    include './Views/html_top_clients.php'; 
                }

                include('./Views/lobby.php');
            } else {
                $errormsg = "   
                <p>Vous n'avez pas de compte ou la combinaison est incorrecte!</p>";
                include('./Views/html_top_login.php');
                include('./Views/login.php');
            }
            break;
            default:
            include('./Views/html_top_login.php');
                include('./Views/login.php');
        endswitch;
    ?>
```